# highcharts: use JSON in drilldown

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts, drilldown

I'm new to the forum and hope to get help to complete my chart!
My problem is to call a json file in the drilldown; this is the result I would get by calling the json (for example)
http://jsfiddle.net/1dmaduwg/2/ and this is the html code and json code that I wrote to call the first json file.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>CHART_1</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>    
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1 style="background: center; text-align: center; color: #E52B50"> ----------> TEST HIGHTCHARTS <----------</h1>
    <div id="container" style="width: auto; height: 400px; max-width: 1000px; margin: auto">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            colors: ['#C80815', '#404040']
        });

    $(document).ready(function() {

             var options = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',


                   backgroundColor: '#EFEFEF', 
                   borderColor: '#FF0000', 
                   borderWidth: 2, 
                   borderRadius: 10, 
                   inverted: false, 
                   type: 'column'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'ACTIVITIES MANAGEMENT ',
                        x: -20 
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: '',
                        x: -20
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: []
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Activity'
                        },
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }]
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                                this.x +': '+ this.y;
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                plotOptions: {   
                   column: {

                   dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'},
                }
                },

                    series: [],

             }

                $.getJSON("test_1.json", function(json) {
                    options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
                    options.series[0] = json[2];            
                    options.series[1] = json[3];
                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                });
            });
          });

    </script>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

test_1.json

```
[
{
"name": "user_name",
"data": ["user_1", "user_2", "user_3", "user_4"]
},
{
"name": "user_id",
"data": ["052193002", "052193007", "052193013", "052193004"]
},
{
"name": "MANAGED",
"data": [52, 13, 42, 10]
},
{
"name": "TO MANAGE",
"data": [12, 3, 32, 1]
}
]
```

when I click on a column or user name I want the right data for each user in a drilldown series.
is the right way to go or I have to make changes to json (test_2) to separate the data?

can anyone help me to write the exact code to insert test_2.json into the Drilldown?

test_2.json

```
//USER_1
[
{
"name": "activity_name",
"data": [ "Activity 1", "Activity 2", "Activity 3"]
},
{
"name": "MANAGED",
"data": [13, 12, 27]
},
{
"name": "TO MANAGE",
"data": [3, 4, 5]
}
],
//USER_2
[
{
"name": "activity_name",
"data": [ "Activity 1", "Activity 2", "Activity 3"]
},
{
"name": "MANAGED",
"data": [3, 7, 3]
},
{
"name": "TO MANAGE",
"data": [1, 0, 2]
}
],
//USER_3
[
{
"name": "activity_name",
"data": [ "Activity 1", "Activity 2", "Activity 3"]
},
{
"name": "MANAGED",
"data": [13, 17, 12]
},
{
"name": "TO MANAGE",
"data": [13, 7, 12]
}
],
//USER_4
[
{
"name": "activity_name",
"data": [ "Activity 1", "Activity 2", "Activity 3"]
},
{
"name": "MANAGED",
"data": [5, 3, 2]
},
{
"name": "TO MANAGE",
"data": [0, 0, 1]
}
]
```

thank you all!!

Answer (score 1):

I would vote for separate files.

It would be optimal (better performance for the chart and lower bandwidth for the connection) to do not force user to download not needed data.